# Navigation Drawer with nested fragments (ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am writing an app which has a `Navigation Drawer` and is using nested fragments.
The navigation drawer is created pretty much as per Android docs - it works.
I want the navigation drawer to be visible always, that's why I have one activity with it, and I just swap fragments. One of the fragments is a `ViewPager`, which in turn has its own fragments as pages.

The navigation is hierarchical like this:

```
- Home
- Fragment 1
-- Subfragment 1.1
-- Subfragment 1.2
-- Subfragment 1.3
- Fragment 2
-- Subfragment 2.1
-- Subfragment 2.2
-- Subfragment 2.3
```

where Fragment is a `ViewPager`, and Subfragments are its pages. All works correctly when I just go to `Fragment` from the drawer, **but I don't know how to switch directly to a `ViewPager's` given page (nested fragment)**.

MainActivity with handling nav drawer clicks:

```
@Override
protected void onNavItemSelected(int id) {
    switch ((int)id) {
        case 1:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit(); 
            break;
        case 100:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case 200:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        .
        .
        .
    }    
}
```

I suppose this should be something with `getChildFragmentManager()` and `ViewPager's` `setCurrentItem()`, but I can't get the first in my Main Activity (or don't know how) and I can't use the second because the pager is not created yet if I do something like this:

```
SubFragment11 a = new SubFragment11();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, a).addToBackStack(null).commit();
a.setCurrentPagerItem(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the ViewPager fragment with a Bundle with a variable to control the selected item. When the Viewpager is created, get that integer and switch to that panel.